# How to create a virtual monitor to confine a full-screen application

Tags: virtual-machine, monitors, fullscreen

I use [Weylus](https://github.com/H-M-H/Weylus#weylus) to draw remotely in my Debian system from my smartphone which dimensions exceed all those of my physical monitors and are not a scale of them. The problem is in reason of their dimensions incompatibilities I do not find a simple way to make the drawing area having no "dead" zones.

My first attempt was to make the application's drawing area (in my case Gimp) taking the most place as possible but in the windowed mode there is no automatic way to shrink the window to its drawing area and in all cases the window title bar would be a "dead" zone (see [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Toggle-drawing-area-to-the-most-widely-as-possible?pid=36075#pid36075)). The full-screen mode can not be used as is, due to the dimensions incompatibilities.

So I asked for myself if I can not "confine" a full-screen in a virtual monitor with the good dimensions that I would access by a window at a scale.

Is it possible ? How ?

Comment: Nobody ? Maybe I imagine the wrong way to achieve this ... So have you another idea ?